# Invoke-Command to Microsoft Exchange

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange-server, invoke-command

a recent patch of Microsoft Exchange changed the way people can use Invoke-Command to an Microsoft Exchange server.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $ExOSessionVariable -ScriptBlock {Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity UserName ; Get-User -Identity UserName}
```

is returning:

```
The syntax is not supported by this runspace. This can occur if the runspace is in no-language mode.
```

This behavior has changed since : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/released-april-2021-exchange-server-security-updates

Microsoft advices to use .AddScript() or .AddCommand(). can someone tell me how to use this commands with invoke-Command ?

Any help is appreciated.

Michael

Comment: You should show how you’re building your session. The variable name suggests exo prefix but that module just wraps graph api.

Answer (score 0):

I think the semicolon is causing the problem in your example.

So this is a workaround rather than a direct answer to your question.

If you replace your script block, for example:

```
$Scriptblock = {  
  Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity UserName
  Get-User -Identity UserName
}

Invoke-Command -Session $ExOSessionVariable -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
```

It should work.